# Where can I find which MEP voted for which laws?

Tags: european-union, parliament

As the title says. Specifically I am interested to know if my local [Member of the European Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_of_the_European_Parliament) voted in favor or against the controversial copyright law that was rejected, but their personal web-pages do not show any information about it.

There must be somewhere to check right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This site is in my opinion the best resource for checking the voting records of MEPs, although for some features you need to create a free account: https://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-voting-statistics.html

You can also check the EuroParl website: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/votes.html?tab=votes

Finally, there is another official European Parliament tool, which is currently being redeveloped: http://parltrack.euwiki.org/

Links to the Copyright In the Digital Single Market law:

http://www.votewatch.eu/en/term8-copyright-in-the-digital-single-market-draft-legislative-resolution-vote-decision-to-enter-into-inte.html#/

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-%2f%2fEP%2f%2fNONSGML%2bPV%2b20180705%2bRES-VOT%2bDOC%2bPDF%2bV0%2f%2fEN&language=EN

To find votes on the EuroParl website, first go to the Plenary, then to Votes, and then to Results of votes. Expand the date range of the bill of interest, and you should find both documents for a roll call and a result of vote.

[image: Plenary - results of votes and roll call]

In the heading of the bill you're looking for, you'll find a code like this:  (A8-0245/2018).

[image: Bill heading and code]

Find this code in the roll call document, and you will find a list of votes for (indicated by a '+'); against (indicated by a '-'); and abstentions (indicated by a '0').

[image: Votes for, against, and abstentions]

A guide can be found here: http://researchbriefings.files.parliament.uk/documents/SN03389/SN03389.pdf

You can also search here by country and parliamentary constituency to find your local MEP, and their parliamentary record:

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/map.html

Comment: Could you add a link to the voting records for the law mentioned?

Comment: @sjoerd Thanks, I've added some more details above.

Comment: How up to date are these statistics? I want to check for the yesterday passed regulation and my decision for the EU election might be based on the yesterdays voting. Considering that the latest entry are from the 18th of April by today, can I even somehow get this information before the EU election? Or is there an intended delay of 1 month before it gets public how such regulations were decided on?

Comment: @dhein when I asked this question, the result went live withing the week of the vote. Just anecdotal evidence, but its likely it will be the same