# How long does it take, before the details of an EU parliament decision get published?

Tags: european-parliament, transparency

I wanted to check the voting outcomes and how individually was being voted for the regulation that passed yesterday by the EU. So I checked the sources given by [Where can I find which MEP voted for which laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/32160/15454).

The problem is, the most recent statistics published there are from the 18th of April. But I would like to have the information for yesterdays voting, as how specific individuals voted is not unlikely to have an impact on my decision who to vote for with the upcoming EU election. So is there any way I can figure this out before election day? Or is the EU withholding these information for a specific time frame, so I won't be able to get to know this, before the election day?

Comment: The European Parliament is not currently in session, hence no records. Can you provide more info about this regulation?

Comment: I don't think there was a plenary session yesterday, the last one ended on the 18th of April. So I can't see how any legislative decision could have been made. What is the name of the regulation?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: Well my bad. I struggle to correctly translate the terms from german into english. It seems to have been more of an council ruling, if that's making more sense.

Comment: I am voting to close this as unclear what I am asking, as I just realized after further research that the premise of my question is nonesense '^.^

Comment: @dhein You might want to transform it into something inquiring over the typical proceedings for the EU parliament. After all there are plenary sessions (which are the decision making sessions), committee meetings, I believe there are also specific meetings for intergroups (transversal to committees). Moreover, I've never used it but I think the [sessions are televised live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroparlTV) so, in theory, you can get the results and MP participation instantly.

Comment: @armatita: Hm, I can try. But wouldn't it then become a dup of the question I link in my OP? Otherwise I am considering putting in that rewording :)

Comment: @dhein Not a duplicate. The EU parliament votes and debates several things. Only some of those are legislation (from the before mentioned plenary sessions). Considering the EU parliament does far more than just voting legislation (which is probably something that it's not clear for most readers) I think it would be useful to have questions regarding its functioning. For example: What does the EU parliament do besides voting on legislation? One could be surprised. Check [this year calendar of sessions for an example](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/ireland/en/european-parliament-calendar).

Comment: @armatita: Ok, I'll try to put this question in such a shape later this evening or by tomorrow. Thanks for the proposal

Comment: @armatita: I gave it another try I hope this is kinda what you had in mind: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/41442/15454 I made it a new post, tho. As this would be quite different from what I was asking here, and hence I felt it would not fit the purpose of editing this one into that. So I still think this one should rather be closed.

Comment: @dhein Looks good (+1). Very well, I'll add my close vote to this one.